# New job on Jenkins on creation of new branch in BitBucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I have integrated my BitBucket to my Jenkins. Is there a way to trigger a new job creation in Jenkins when a new branch is created in BitBucket?. The job name should be same as the new branch created. Can I do it with scripts, or Jenkins CLI or using BitBucket API.
I am new to Jenkins, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried plugin that mentioned in answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. This could be done. I recommend you to look at [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin). This is really convenient plugin. Moreover you could also put your job scripts under version control system (`VCS`).

All scripting is done in `Groovy` language. Find example below:

```
def project = 'quidryan/aws-sdk-test'
def branchApi = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/${project}/branches")
def branches = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(branchApi.newReader())
branches.each {
    def branchName = it.name
    def jobName = "${project}-${branchName}".replaceAll('/','-')
    job(jobName) {
        scm {
            git("git://github.com/${project}.git", branchName)
        }
        steps {
            maven("test -Dproject.name=${project}/${branchName}")
        }
    }
}
```

Also take a look at online job playground for this plugin - [Jenkins Job DSL Playground](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/).

It is just a recommendation where to look at. Probably you will have more concrete questions on this topic. But definitely take a look at this plugin.